# HTTP Get request in C

Tags: c, http

I'm just learning to code in C, and I wan't to know if anyone can point me in the right direction, or give me an example for a simple HTTP Get request in C.

Thanks :)

Comment: Use correct tags in the question. Otherwise you may miss many answers.

Answer (score 6):

You may checkout [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/). And here are some [examples](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html). It could be as easy as (taken from the doc):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "curl.haxx.se");
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* always cleanup */ 
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return 0;
}
```